# submit button generates if else statement

Tags: php

I wanted my submit button, when clicked to use an if else statement.  If a field is 6+ the submit should send an email, if it is not it should redirect to a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need `if($isSending >= 6):` and perhaps check for `$isSending === false` but apart from that it should work.

Is there a specific part you are having problems with?

Comment: I wasn't sure if the the two if statements would contradict. I will try that edit thanks

Comment: I have updated my question now if you could take a look. thanks

Answer (score 0):

So you have 6 fields in your form?

if so just do this then:

```
if($_POST['fieldname'] != null)
{
  send mail
}
else
{
  redirect
}
```

you can do this to all 6 fields or you can just simplify it easily.

Comment: and here i thought you have 6 fields in your form,well if it only concerns the value placed by the user then if($var >= 6) is sufficient enough.